# Python zeep. Force not to use a Proxy

Tags: python, proxy, zeep

How can i use python zeep module and configure the connection to connect with no    proxy?
I need to access an internal WSDL. That means no proxy is needed.

I have tried to create the client:

```
  from zeep import client
  client = Client("myURL")
```

But i am getting an error because is trying to connect with a default proxy
Regards.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521535/requests-how-to-disable-bypass-proxy , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47195778/unable-to-connect-to-soap-api-with-proxy-setting

Answer (score 0):

Using the information provided in the links provided by Dima,
the following worked for me:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.trust_env = False
transport = Transport(timeout=10)
transport.session = session
client = Client("your url", transport=transport)
```